# How to download fusion table data into R

Tags: r

I am trying to download the Iraq Wikileaks data into R, but need help to do it successfully.  I'm not understanding the result at the end about "moved temporarily"

There are several links available on this page.

http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2010/oct/23/wikileaks-iraq-data-journalism#data

I tried to do download the fusion table that doesn't require a login using this code.

library(RCurl)

x = getURL("http://www.google.com/fusiontables/exporttable?query=select+col0%2Ccol1%2Ccol2%2Ccol3%2Ccol4%2Ccol5%2Ccol6%2Ccol7%2Ccol8%2Ccol9%2Ccol10%2Ccol11%2Ccol12%2Ccol13%2Ccol14%2Ccol15%2Ccol16%2Ccol17%2Ccol18+from+273326")

y <- read.csv(text = x)

However, here is all that I end up with in y.

> str(y)
>   'data.frame':   8 obs. of  1 variable:
>    $ X.HTML.: Factor w/ 8 levels "","",..: 6 7 2 4 5 8 1 3
>   y
>                                                                                                  X.HTML.
>   1                                                                                               
>   2                                                                     Moved Temporarily
>   3                                                                                              
>   4                                                                  
>   5
>
> ## Moved Temporarily
>
> 6 The document has moved http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=273326>here.
>   7                                                                                              
>   8

Answer (score 1):

```
y<-download.file("http://www.google.com/fusiontables/exporttable?query=select+col0%2Ccol1%2Ccol2%2Ccol3%2Ccol4%2Ccol5%2Ccol6%2Ccol7%2Ccol8%2Ccol9%2Ccol10%2Ccol11%2Ccol12%2Ccol13%2Ccol14%2Ccol15%2Ccol16%2Ccol17%2Ccol18+from+273326",destfile="iraq.csv")
# file iraq.csv will be stored in your working directory

my_data<-read.csv("iraq.csv")
head(my_data)
```

Comment: Thanks again for this simple insight on how to access the data.  I'll be posting some analysis on r-bloggers.com in a couple of days.